# Difference between `x in y` vs `y[x]`

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, dictionary, hash

Using JavaScript, is there any difference in terms of performance or behavior between

```
let foo = {
  a: true,
  b: false,
  c: true
}

'c' in foo

and

foo['c']

?
```

Always wondered that, not sure how to search for an answer. The only obvious difference is that `foo['c']` will return false if 'c' points to a falsy value, where as `'c' in foo` will return true if foo has key 'c'.

**The reason I ask the question:**

In many cases I want to just store a key (for quick search) and I do not care about the value:

```
 let foo = {    // the keys are important, values of no consequence
      a: undefined,
      b: undefined,
      c: undefined
  }
```

I am wondering if it is best practice to just store the keys, without even assigning a value.

```
if(!('a' in foo)){
    foo['a'] = undefined;
 }
```

It just seems strange to give the hash any values, when I don't need to use the values, I only need to store a key.

Comment: Easiest way is to create a test via https://jsperf.com/

Comment: right, but besides the case of b (which I described) is there a difference in lookup time or anything else?

Comment: The "obvious difference" is the difference, yes, and it’s kind of really important. Who cares about lookup time when they do different things? Use the check that coveys the correct meaning.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I am wondering if there are any other differences, that difference is obviously important, but it's also obvious :)

Comment: ?? `in` operator checks whether a property exists in an object or not, `foo['c']` retrieves the value.These are totally different tasks ... Maybe you should elaborate the question ..?

Comment: I will explain why I am asking the question, I will update the question momentarily.

Comment: Well, performance aside, checking `'c' in foo` checks for _existence_, whether or not it's `undefined`, whereas `foo['c']` has no way of communicating existence if `foo['c']` is initialized as `undefined`.

Comment: If you want a set, use the `Set` type.

Comment: @Ryan I will check out Set, but things like Map and Set usually have methods that are less convenient to work with than POJSOs.

Comment: If the keys are important, you can very well add a key to an object with value of `undefined`. This also creates a micro-level performance advantage when retrieving the value of the property, JS doesn't have to search through the prototype chain to "find" `undefined` at the end, when the key exists.

Comment: if you want to store keys only, why can't you use arrays instead?

Comment: look up time in objects is O(1) arrays of O(n) right?

Comment: @AlexanderMills _ideal_ lookup is O(1) for objects, but if they have 1000s of keys, that best-case scenario could conceivably deteriorate. Obviously not as quickly as array lookup. Even a binary search for a key on a sorted array would be less efficient than an optimized hash table, and in that case you'd have to consider the lack of performance for key _insertion_ on a sorted array.

Comment: @AlexanderMills oh and for arrays, you could either have O(n) lookup and O(1) insertion, or O(log n) lookup and O(n) insertion. With a tree, though, you could have O(log n) lookup and O(log n) insertion, but you'd have to implement that yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you answer your own question with

> The only obvious difference is that foo['c'] will return false if 'c' points to a falsy value, where as 'c' in foo will return true if foo has key 'c'.

```
'c' in foo
```

checks if there is a key named 'c' in foo

and

```
foo['c']
```

returns its value

Answer (score 2):

While this has probably been sufficiently answered in comments, that's not what they're for, so here's a proper recommendation: use [`Set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

Unlike objects, they support *all* strings as keys, even ones like `"__proto__"` and `"hasOwnProperty"` (if you cared about using those).

In addition, they support other types for keys as well. Of particular interest is the use of non-primitives as keys, and also `NaN`, which is special because it doesn't equal itself.

```js
let lookup = new Set()

console.log('arbitrary strings:')

lookup.add('__proto__')
lookup.add('hasOwnProperty')

checkHas('__proto__')
checkHas('hasOwnProperty')

lookup.add(5)
lookup.add(NaN)

console.log('other types:')

checkHas(5)
checkHas(NaN)

const myObject = {}

lookup.add(myObject)

console.log('some arbitrary object:')

checkHas({})

console.log('myObject:')

checkHas(myObject)

lookup.add(myObject)

function checkHas(key) {
  console.log(key, lookup.has(key))
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```